# why doesn't regex work in vimscript (while it does in normal search)?

Tags: vimscript, regular-expression

I have simple regex to search for lines that only contain alphabetic characters: `^\(\a\)\{1,}$` which works in normal search `/^\(\a\)\{1,}$` but not when invoked from my script:

```
"in .vimrc file:
function DiaryTagBrowser()
  let line = getline('.')
  "if line =~ "^\(\a\)\{1,}$"
  if match(line, "^\(\a\)\{1,}$")
    w! /tmp/vimwiki-tag-list.txt
    enew | set ft=vimwiki | set modifiable
    exe 'read !tagshow.py ' . line
    set nomodifiable
  else
    echo "not on a diaryTag"
  endif
endfunction
command! DiaryTagBrowser : call DiaryTagBrowser()
nnoremap <Enter> :DiaryTagBrowser <Enter>
```

Testing on a file that looks like:

```
tagOne
tagTwo
tagThree
not a tag
tagFour
```

When doing a normal search via `/` the lines 1, 2, 3, and 5 all match, while line 4 does not match.  This is correct/proper/as-expected.

But that same regex in my vimscript doesn't work.  When using:

`if match(line, "^\(\a\)\{1,}$")` the code always runs (the regex also evaluates to true) though it should never run when `<Enter>` is pressed on line 4.

And when using:

`if line =~ "^\(\a\)\{1,}$"` the code never runs (regex is always false, always echoing "not on a diaryTag") though it should always run `<Enter>` is pressed on lines 1-3 and 5.

I've tried many different alterations of the regex expression, but considering the inconsistency I just described the problem does not seem to be with the expression but with how it's invoked.

In this maddening endeavor I've read through: [1](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/vimscript/) [2](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/19.html) [3](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/21.html) [4](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/22.html) [5](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/31.html) [6](http://vimregex.com/) [7](https://learnbyexample.gitbooks.io/vim-reference/content/Regular_Expressions.html) [8](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699675/3089106) [9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55366871/how-to-check-if-a-string-matches-a-pattern-in-vim) and several other posts... without finding an explanation of this at all.

What's going on here?

Comment: See `:h expr-quote` and `:h expr-'`. Try `:echo "^\(\a\)\{1,}$"` and `:echo '^\(\a\)\{1,}$'`

Comment: If I change to single quotes then `if line =~ '^\(\a\)\{1,}$'` will work... but the same regex used like `if match(line, '^\(\a\)\{1,}$')` evaluates a true when it should be false and as false when it should be true.  Why is that?

Comment: `match()` is neither true nor false.

Comment: can you explain?  When using `match()` the logic fails when I expect it to pass and it passes when it should fail.

Comment: Does `match()` return the literal string that matches?

Comment: Do you know how to use help? Type `:h match()` and press enter.

Comment: "Does match() return the literal string that matches?" was a dumb question, the `:h match()` and my first experiment of `let match...` confused me.  Second experiment and further re-reading clarified.  Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Off the top of my head, `'\A'` is a simpler (and presumably more efficient) regexp. (You’d obviously need to swap your if and else branches, or use `!~` instead of `=~`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the [links referenced](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12699675/3089106) put the expression in double quotes `"`.  Using single quotes `'` instead fixes the problem with `if line =~ '^\(\a\)\{1,}$'`.

In order for `match()` to be used in logic like this it needs to be compared to something like:

`if match(line, '^\(\a\)\{1,}$') == 0` since `match()` returns `0` when it finds a match at the first character or list item (which is the case in this example).